# Save expression to variable

Tags: variables, sh

I want to save the result of the expression to a variable.  If I use echo it works but not with a variable
The version variable returns "Nextcloud 18.0.2"

`version=$(sudo -u www php /usr/local/www/nextcloud/occ --version)`

`newversion=${version} | sed -e 's/Nextcloud //'`

`echo ${version} | sed -e 's/Nextcloud //'`
returns "18.0.2"

`echo $newversion` returns a blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `echo` and a command substitution `$(...)`:

```
newversion=$(echo "$version" | sed 's/Nextcloud //')
```

or you could use a parameter expansion to remove the shortest prefix pattern

```
newversion=${version#Nextcloud }
```